# webview.loadurl() Vs super.loadurl() in android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, android-websettings

What is the difference b/w these two methods

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

and `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`

When i am using second one my application running well but when i am using first one it looks either blank or in some cases a alert dialog appear said about plugins...

I want to make application on Phonegap, I exactly want to know that which one is better approach for it.

**When i am using `webview.loadurl()` and call `addJavascriptInterface()`, In that case the functions are written into the HTML file under the `<script>` tag are not invoke on click of any button(defined in HTML),**

Please help me, i am stuck, Thanks in advance...

Comment: if your application is only for android then use first approach it is faster than second approach

Comment: @IllegalArgument Thanks for your reply, is first approach is compatible for all platforms and can we make a toast from second approach in android

Comment: nope first approach is only for android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Phonegap project the Main Activity .java class contains `extends DroidGap`

so in this case

`super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`

is useful because `Webview` of `DroidGap` capture this url.

And in your Android app your activity .java class contains  `extends Activity`
 so

`webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`

The `Webview` specified by you in your activity class will capture the Url .

Comment: thanks, can you explain me about the bold part of my question ?

Comment: did you set the Webview client?

Comment: Here is my question regarding this, can you look at it once? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299814/how-to-control-javascript-in-android-phonegap)

Comment: I answered your question. let me know if you have any problem regarding it.